# Excel VBA code to Force Values Only Paste causes strange behavior when pasting objects

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a spreadsheet where users enter survey data and, like many have others, needed to prevent the users from overwriting various formatting features. I used the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
Target.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = True
End Sub
```

The code works great for forcing values only paste after copying or cutting cells. When you cut or copy, the very next cell that you click on receives the paste, you don't have to use Ctrl+V or right click and select paste.

However, during testing it was discovered that if you cut or copy an object (shape, inserted picture, etc.) then it will continue pasting after the first mouse click. It will paste again and again with each subsequent click without stopping.

I verified this behavior in Excel 2010 and 2013.

Does anyone know how to modify this to correct the odd behavior when pasting objects?

Comment: What about save the format before edit and restore the format after edit? , But I don't know if Excel exposes those events for cells. If not use a form to control input or even better `MS-Access`.

Comment: How about identifying the object type if it's string or Object? [GetFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getformat-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow only paste value method, just put the below code under the Microsoft Excel Objects `ThisWorkbook` (i.e. not under any module).

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim UndoString As String, srce As Range
    On Error GoTo err_handler
    UndoString = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
    If Left(UndoString, 5) <> "Paste" And UndoString <> "Auto Fill" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Undo
    If UndoString = "Auto Fill" Then
        Set srce = Selection
        srce.Copy
        Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.SendKeys "{ESC}"
        Union(Target, srce).Select
    Else
        Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
err_handler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Note that though it'll work most of the times, it may well happen occasionally especially for external contents consisting features like wrap text, etc that nothing is copied.

That being said, the objective of preserving the format will still be maintained as it will force the user to try paste as value (or press <kbd>F2</kbd> key and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>), instead of pasting directly.

Disclaimer: I don't take any credit for this code block as it's widely available in the internet.

Comment: Thanks Curious, I've used this code block a few times on other projects and it certainly works. Unfortunately, this will be running on a corporate intranet consisting entirely of terminals and it causes a fairly big performance hit / lag of up to several seconds after each paste, longer if pasting multiple cells. The code that I'm trying to get working was much quicker. However, if I can't get the other working, then this will be the fallback solution.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the accepted answer to cover the scenario where a user tries to drag one cell to another destination on the sheet. This is to preserve formatting but more importantly in my case to prevent named ranges being moved around a protected sheet (for certain cells that are left unlocked so that data can be entered.)

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim UndoString As String, srce As Range
On Error GoTo err_handler
UndoString = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
If Left(UndoString, 5) <> "Paste" And UndoString <> "Auto Fill" And UndoString <> "Drag and Drop" Then
    Exit Sub
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Undo
If UndoString = "Auto Fill" Then
    Set srce = Selection
    srce.Copy
    Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.SendKeys "{ESC}"
    Union(Target, srce).Select
Else
    Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
err_handler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```